# Add missing values to a frequency table in R

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a list of the format

```
>count_temp
      Week freq
    1  00    1
    2  01    1
    3  02    1
    4  03    1
    5  10    1
    6  12    2
    7  14    1
```

In the Week column, some data is missing (Weeks 4,5,6 etc..). I want these missing values to be included in my table with the frequency value '0'.

I tried out the answer suggested in [How to create missing values in table in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372462/how-to-create-missing-values-in-table-in-r) but my levels for both the columns are completely different. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: ...as described in `?table`.