# Fill sequence by factor

Tags: r

I need to fill $Year with missing values of the sequence by the factor of $Country. The $Count column can just be padded out with 0's.

```
Country Year Count
A       1    1
A       2    1
A       4    2
B       1    1
B       3    1
```

So I end up with

```
Country Year Count
A       1    1
A       2    1
A       3    0
A       4    2
B       1    1
B       2    0
B       3    1
```

Hope that's clear guys, thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Comment: Sorry for closing; reopened now. I guess this is different enough from the usual expand.grid solutions. Here for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996452/r-find-and-add-missing-non-existing-rows-in-time-related-data-frame and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954602/handling-missing-combinations-of-factors-in-r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
# d is your original data.frame
setDT(d)
foo <- d[, .(Year = min(Year):max(Year)), Country]
res <- merge(d, foo, all.y = TRUE)[is.na(Count), Count := 0]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is a `dplyr`/`tidyr` solution using `complete` and `full_seq`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% group_by(Country) %>% complete(Year=full_seq(Year,1),fill=list(Count=0))
  Country  Year Count
    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1       A     1     1
2       A     2     1
3       A     3     0
4       A     4     2
5       B     1     1
6       B     2     0
7       B     3     1
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar to @PoGibas' answer:

```
library(data.table)

# set default values
def = list(Count = 0L)

# create table with all levels    
fullDT = setkey(DT[, .(Year = seq(min(Year), max(Year))), by=Country])

# initialize to defaults
fullDT[, names(def) := def ]

# overwrite from data
fullDT[DT, names(def) := mget(sprintf("i.%s", names(def))) ]
```

which gives

```
   Country Year Count
1:       A    1     1
2:       A    2     1
3:       A    3     0
4:       A    4     2
5:       B    1     1
6:       B    2     0
7:       B    3     1
```

This generalizes to having more columns (besides `Count`). I guess similar functionality exists in the "tidyverse", with a name like "expand" or "complete".

Answer (score 4):

Another base R idea can be to split on Country, use `setdiff` to find the missing values from the `seq(max(Year))`, and `rbind` them to original data frame. Use `do.call` to `rbind` the list back to a data frame, i.e.

```
d1 <- do.call(rbind, c(lapply(split(df, df$Country), function(i){
                       x <- rbind(i, data.frame(Country = i$Country[1], 
                                                 Year = setdiff(seq(max(i$Year)), i$Year), 
                                                 Count = 0)); 
                        x[with(x, order(Year)),]}), make.row.names = FALSE))
```

which gives,

> ```
>      Country Year Count
>   1       A    1     1
>   2       A    2     1
>   3       A    3     0
>   4       A    4     2
>   5       B    1     1
>   6       B    2     0
>   7       B    3     1
> ```

Comment: instead of the `lapply(split(df,df$Country),function(i)..` you can use 
`by(df,df$Country,function(i)...` or `tapply`

Comment: @Onyambu true. I guess `lapply(split...))` comes to me more naturally. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

```
> setkey(DT,Country,Year)
> DT[setkey(DT[, .(min(Year):max(Year)), by = Country], Country, V1)]
   Country Year Count
1:       A    1     1
2:       A    2     1
3:       A    3    NA
4:       A    4     2
5:       B    1     1
6:       B    2    NA
7:       B    3     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `dplyr` and `tidyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  do(data_frame(Country = unique(.$Country),
                Year = full_seq(.$Year, 1))) %>%
  full_join(dt, by = c("Country", "Year")) %>%
  replace_na(list(Count = 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach in base R that uses `tapply`, `do.call`, `range`, and `seq`, to calculate year sequences. Then constructs a data.frame from the named list that is returned, merges this onto the original which adds the desired rows, and finally fills in missing values.

```
# get named list with year sequences
temp <- tapply(dat$Year, dat$Country, function(x) do.call(seq, as.list(range(x))))

# construct data.frame
mydf <- data.frame(Year=unlist(temp), Country=rep(names(temp), lengths(temp)))

# merge onto original
mydf <- merge(dat, mydf, all=TRUE)

# fill in missing values
 mydf[is.na(mydf)] <- 0
```

This returns

```
mydf
  Country Year Count
1       A    1     1
2       A    2     1
3       A    3     0
4       A    4     2
5       B    1     1
6       B    2     0
7       B    3     1
```